# Check for null in enum property

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I've got an enum property that I'm using to populate a dropdown as part of my form that looks like this:

```
 public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Type of Enum")]
    public EnumType? Type { get; set; }
}

public enum EnumType
{
    option1 = 1,
    option2 = 2,
    option3 = 3,
    option4 = 4
}
```

The form submits to another controller, where I'm trying to check for null in the enum type:

```
 public class ResultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Result
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), model.EnumType))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }           
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I try `..../result?Type=5` `RedirectToAction` works, but when I try `..../result?Type=` I get `ArgumentNullException`.

Note: Adding `None=0` in the Enum is not an option for me, I don not want none to show up in the dropdown list.

How can I check for null in the controller? Is there a best practice in this regard?

Comment: Should it be `HasValue`? As `Type` is a `nullable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, based on your model the `Type` property is required.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Type of Enum")]
    public EnumType? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Second, you need to check that the enum value is really defined on the `EnumType` declaration, then you don't need to call `Enum.isDefined` method in your action. Just decorate your `Type` property with data annotation attribute `EnumDataType(typeof(EnumType))` which will do that job. So your model will look like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(EnumType))]
    [DisplayName("Type of Enum")]
    public EnumType? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, in your controller action just clean it so it look this:

```
// GET: Result
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    // IsValid will check that the Type property is setted and will exectue 
    // the data annotation attribute EnumDataType which check that 
    // the enum value is correct.
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly check whether the value is `null` before using it in `IsDefined()`.

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    if(!model.EnumType.HasValue)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }           
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), model.EnumType))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }           
    return View();
}
```

---

A shorter version is to use the [null-coalesce operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to use `0` instead of `null` in the call to `IsDefined()`:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), model.EnumType ?? 0))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }           
    return View();
}
```